# Django Heroku : python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Tags: django, heroku

I am deploying a Django website on Heroku. My project is called **mysite-project** which contains at its root `manage.py` and `Procfile`

I can visit the heroku website after I run `git push heroku master`.

And the website shows:

[image]

I am assuming I do not see anything (navbar, initial page, etc.) because I did not run migrate.

If I do:

```
heroku run python manage.py migrate
```

I get the error:

> python: can't open file 'manage.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Which makes no sense since I am in the right directory.
In fact:

- I can run `python manage.py runserver` and locahost works
- `git ls-files manage.py` --outputs--> `manage.py`

**BUT**
If I do:

```
heroku run bash
ls manage.py
```

I get:

> ls: cannot access 'manage.py': No such file or directory

It seems that `manage.py` is in my local but not in my heroku.

**Procfile**

```
web: gunicorn mysite-project.wsgi
```

Comment: Where you able to solve this issue? @Magofoco

Comment: I was not, I used DigitalOcean instead of Heroku.

Answer (score 2):

First use `heroku logs --source app --tail` to make sure that the **Build succeeded**.
If the build is successful, make sure you have your project at the root of the git repo.
I had the same problem because my Django project was not at the root of the git repo.
My file hierarchy was first like (assuming the name of the project prototype and it has one app named app)
├──git_repo
        ├──Procfile
        ├──requirements.txt
        ├──new_folder
                ├──prototype (folder)
                ├──app (folder)
                ├──.gitignore
                ├──manage.py
                ├──db.sqlite3

I changed the hierarchy to the following and it worked
├──git_repo
        ├──Procfile
        ├──requirements.txt
        ├──prototype (folder)
        ├──app (folder)
        ├──.gitignore
        ├──manage.py
        ├──db.sqlite3

Answer (score 0):

The welcome you see when you visit the site (as well as the fact, that you can't find `manage.py` with `ls` on the server) tells you, that you haven't successfully pushed your django project to Heroku yet. Try and run `git push heroku master`.

It may be that the push has failed, in which case you should consult the [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-app-configuration). Specifically, run

```sh
$ pip install gunicorn django-heroku
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

...and then add

```py
import django_heroku
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

...to the bottom of `settings.py`. Also don't forget to set `STATIC_ROOT='staticfiles'` in `settings.py`aswell.

Comment: What do you get from running `git push heroku master`? Is the push successfull?

Answer (score 0):

That screenshot attached indicates you have just created app in heroku but not pushed your local repository code to heroku app.

```
git push heroku master
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this error too!
I solved it by specifying the path:

```
python <your_project_name>/manage.py migrate
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was because I was using a branch name other than `master`. My branch name was `heroku_branch`, so to make things work properly, I pushed it this way

```
git push heroku heroku_branch:master
```

It was pushed this time and worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

For django + heroku

```
web: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:\$PORT
```